# fa class loads, fab class does not, the result is missing icons

Tags: css, font-awesome

Font Awesome has awesome for me for quite a while.  However, I noticed that recently there's been a bit of a change and I haven't been successful in adjusting. Specifically, the **fa** class has been deprecated, according to what I read on the fontawesome site. Now we are supposed to use **fab** for projects like mine. Unfortunately, **fab** won't load. **fa** will still load just fine, but not for all the icons, just some of the icons.

Please see here, upper right corner: https://circularsmc.nationbuilder.com/

Twitter and Facebook are using the old **fa** class and they are loading.

Instagram is not loading using the new **fab** class. I tried it again next to it using the old fa class, but that's not working, either. (both are there, right next to each other, for reference).

I'm a bit flummoxed. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I checked the Support page but it doesn't look like this issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

While using fontawesome, you need to be aware of the different style sheets used by this library.

1-`fas` for solid

2-`far` for regular

3-`fal` for light

4- `fab` for brand

All of these style sheets beside the original `fa` style one. So, if your `fa` icons are working and `fab` is not, then you have to make sure that you have linked the `fab` style sheet either by downloading it locally inside your project or adding its cdn link to you html file.

Follow this link to [use fontawesome cdn links of any style that you need](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome)

I hope this is informative for you

Comment: That's it! It worked! Thanks for the link to that page!